# How do I write files to a USB without being root?

Tags: linux, usb, mount, debian-squeeze

I have a 4GB USB stick which I partitioned using `sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb` and formatted using `sudo mkfs /dev/sdb1`. It's currently set to ID `83` with System `Linux` when I run `sudo fdisk -l` on my Debian Squeeze.

I use `pmount` to mount the external USB drives. So doing a `pmount /dev/sdb1` mounts it to `/media/usb0` because I have the ff. line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/usb0    auto    rw,user,noauto    0    0
```

After issuing the `pmount` command, the USB is mounted to `/media/usb0` -- doing an `ls -l /media/usb0` gives me:

```
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Mar   2 20:08 lost+found
```

So I go about my business and try to copy a file to `/media/usb0` but I get the error below:

```
$ cp ~/foo.bar /media/usb0
cp: cannot create regular file `/media/usb0/foo.bar': Permission denied
```

But when I issue the same `cp` command with `sudo`, I am able to copy the file.

Why does this happen? I tried other USB drive I have and I am able to write to them without this error. Was there something wrong with the way I formatted or repartitioned the USB stick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You formatted the sdb1 partition using an `ext*`** file system (either *ext2*, *ext3*, or *ext4*; I cannot recall the default). This is the default file system on Linux systems, and uses **Unix file permissions** to determine who can modify files or directories. Fresh filesystems always start off with the root (`/media/usb0` in this case) being owned by `root:root`, and usually with permissions only allowing modification by the owner.

To see this for yoruself, mount the filesystem, then run `ls -ld /media/usb0` to see the current ownership/perms. My guess is:

```
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Mar   2 20:08 /media/usb0
```

A simple fix would be to a) **`chown`** the mounted file system to your own Linux account, or b) to give everyone write permission with **`chmod`**.

However, in the end, this wouldn't be a good solution, since the files created would become owned by your UID, not the username; this would quickly result in **account mismatches** when the USB drive is connected to a different system. Assuming you can connect it at all, that is – **Windows does not support ext3** without extra trickery, so NTFS (`mkfs.ntfs`) or FAT32 (`mkfs.vfat`) would be a much better choice for the file system.

Comment: I tried doing `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1` and `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1` but I get the error `sudo: mkfs.xxxx: command not found` where `xxxx` is either `ntfs` and `vfat`. How do I get that to work on Debian Squeeze?

Comment: @Eric: Install *ntfs-3g* + *ntfsprogs* + *dosfstools*.

Comment: Ok, I installed that. Now when I try to mount, I get this error: `ntfs-3g-mount: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied`. What do I do about this?

Answer (score 4):

This happens on later Debian systems (e.g. jessie) as well with certain fat32 or ext3,4 formatted USB flash drives. You need to **remove** (or comment out) the following line from your */etc/fstab*:

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/usb0    auto    rw,user,noauto    0    0
```

After this you'll have your USB drive mounted automatically under your regular user account's permission and not root. See detailed info on Debian forums on [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=107470) link.

After that your USB drive will mount smoothly with your user write permission :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo` and change permissions with `chmod` command.

See my answer in that question to see how to use `chmod`:

- [What is the meaning of "chmod 666"?](https://superuser.com/questions/295591/what-is-the-meaning-of-chmod-666/295615#295615)

I suggest you to use `chmod 777` to allow all (using `ls -l` it will show `drwxrwxrwx`).

Answer (score 1):

If your filesystem is FAT16 or FAT32 you have to use this command:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usb0 -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

For more info visit the link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Mount_the_Drive

Answer (score 0):

Go to file system media via the GUI. Right click on the USB drive you want to copy to and select - Open as Root. Type in password. Then you can copy delete, drag and drop. All Good

Comment: As alluded to above by @Sven, root:root in the ownership is the reason open as root at terminal or gui OR  use chown to change either the owner or group to allow yourself to use that usb as expected.